# How to detect whether an audio file stored in document directory is playable or not programmatically Xcode iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, playback, detect

I am working on Playing an audio file stored in Document Directory using AVAudioPlayer.The Audio exists in directory and has 82 bytes of size.

I want to detect whether this audio is Playable or not.

```
/*save the Audio file in Document Directory */

NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

/*Get the Path  to Application Documents Directory*/
NSArray *docDir=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

/*append the neccessary file extension */
NSLog(@"%d",bt.tag);
int a=bt.tag-10000;
NSString *filepathStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@.mp3",docDir,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",a]];

/*Check if my crrent file exists in the Documents Directory*/

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filepathStr])
{


    NSData *dat = [fileManager contentsAtPath:filepathStr];
    NSLog(@"data is %d",[dat length]);
    if(player)
    {
        [player stop];
        [player release];
        player=nil;
    }

    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filepathStr] options:nil];

   /* You can then check its playable property:*/

    if (asset.playable) 
    {
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:dat error:nil];
        player.delegate = self;
        [player play];  




        //Do Something
    }
```

I have other playable audios also stored in Document directory those are playing fine.
I have used the AVURLAsset and tried to check its property "playable" but couldn't succeed as the AVURLAsset object is not formed.

This audio file has a size of 82 bytes but its not playing not even in the itunes.

Comment: I have also used                AVAsset *avAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filepathStr] options:nil];
   
 if (avAsset.playable) 
        {/* its playable*/
          }   But AVURLAsset *asset is nil

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution to this we can detect the audio is playable or not by using the following code

```
 NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filepathStr]; 
     AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
  /* You can then check its playable property:*/

        if (asset.playable) 
        {

       player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:dat error:nil];
            player.delegate = self;
            [player play];  
 }
```